# clang++ linker undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
$clang++ main.cpp -o out
```

Got following error, the same error happens when changing to g++. I have tested on some simple simple c++ code, the command works fine. So it the problem in that PNG class file? However, the same files worked on my MacOS before, but suddenly failed today.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"PNG::writeToFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,   std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
"PNG::PNG(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,  std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
"PNG::PNG(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
"PNG::~PNG()", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
"PNG::operator()(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
"PNG::width() const", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
 "PNG::height() const", referenced from:
  _main in main-f6a06a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I don't see any other objects or libraries being linked or any other files being compiled on that command line. Where is PNG implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss providing static/shared to the linker to resolve the linker errors for the methods mentioned? Also note that clang++ is a different compiler compared to g++ and hence need the static/shared libraries compiled prior by the same compiler you are using (clang++).

Comment: On a mac, g++ has been clang for a very long time - at least 5 years. But yes, adding the library to the command-line is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
clang++ main.cpp -o out -lpng
```

Here's why: You are not providing the library that contains the implementation of your PNG library (libpng most likely). You need `-lpng` added to your compiler, so that it links with the relevant library. It may not be exactly `-lpng` in your particular case, but it's definitely a "missing library". Without knowing exactly what library you are trying to use (you didn't provide some source to "try the fix with").

As pointed out in the comment: you are using some kind of C++ wrapper on top, the above is probably not enough - but without knowing exactly which C++ wrapper on the png functionality you are actually using, it's hard to say what the command-line should look like.

Perhaps [this](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/doc/0.2.9/)

Comment: IIRC libpng is a C library, here what appears to be missing is some C++ wrapper.

Comment: Yes, probably. I'll add a bit more text to explain.